# Find number of rows deleted from onChange event

Tags: google-apps-script

In the `onChange` event, for the "REMOVED_ROW" type for a SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder I would like to get the number of rows deleted. I can use `sheet.getActiveRange()` to get the row that was deleted if it is only one that got deleted. If it is more than one I have no way of knowing how many got deleted.
How to find out this number?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that we can find the number of rows deleted by simply calling:

```
sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows()
```

Comment: Superb! @riyafa